# Outlook 2010 - assign fullsized pictures on a contact card - HOW?

Tags: outlook, size, photo

I've faced with the next problem: I do not understand why but then I am assigning the proper picture in a high resolution (300x300dpi, file size ~1.5MB, photo's dimensions 700x500px) to my favorite contact at Outlook 2010 - this f... Outlook is stretching down my picture.
As a result I have picture with next output data: unknown dpi, file size ~15KB, photo's dimensions 300x200. Tested by two different operations available inside the contact's card dialog window:
calling the context menu on a thumbnail of my picture - and choosing menu item "COPY".
And exporting of the contact into the vCard file. After that - decoding saved picture from base64 format into a real binary JPEG format.

Questions: WHY outlook is changing the original quality and output data of my picture?
And which final dimensions the Outlook can accept as nonchangable? Only photo 200x300?
HOW to overcome this problem and forcibly to assign to contact's card exactly that picture which I wanted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The picture will be resized if its dimensions are greater than 314x314 pixels and/or the size is greater than 50,000 bytes.

You can assign a picture with different attributes, but you will need to add it as a regular attachment (`Attachments.Add`), then add all the picture related properties using `Attachment.PropertyAccesor.SetProperty` - look at a contact with an existing picture with [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author): select the contact, click IMessage, go to the GetAttachmentTable tab, double click to open the attachment. In particlar, you will need to add `PR_ATTACHMENT_CONTACTPHOTO`, `PR_ATTACHMENT_FLAGS`, `PR_ATTACHMENT_HIDDEN`, `PR_ATTACHMENT_LINKID`, `PR_ATTACH_FLAGS` properties.

Keep in mind that if the picture is too big, Outlook will not show it in the Card view in the folder.

Comment: where on an official pages I can find this info? Or M$ is not providing such information and to find such info we can only by using some hacker's knowledges?
And does it mean that I can't in an anyway to assign picture with a perfect output data, like big dpi, good w*h dimensions and etc....

Comment: next question)) this additional assignments make sense only from programmer's point of view - but what about an ordinary user? How he|she can make these steps? I understand that I can add an attachment - but how to add all those properties? Very simply?

Comment: Dmitry! can we communicate with you regarding this problem from the behalf of one developer from 4pda.ru site?
P.S. - I've tested current situation - outlook IS resizing the photo if any from both parameters is not in range: the dimensions are greater than 314x314 pixels !or! the size is greater than 50,000 bytes.

Comment: P.S. What about the restrictions for Outlook 2007 and 2013?
Are they the same? 314x314px or 50KB?

Comment: I have this information from one of MS support engineers. I do not think this is officially documented. I am not sure I understand about your point about an end user - Outlook will always resize the picture for you.

Comment: pls take a look at my e-mail which I've sent to you recently on your site's official email outspy-blach-blach... email has subject field = "помните вопрос Outlook 2010 - assign fullsized pictures on a contact card - HOW?"